# Generating all n-tuples from a string

Tags: python, string

Is there a simple, pythonic, way to generate all n-tuples of a given length from a string?

For example, I would like `generateTuples("Hello, World!", 3)` to produce the following:

```
[ "Hel", "ell", "llo", "lo,", "o, ", ", W", " Wo", "Wor", "orl", "rld", "ld!" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = "Hello, World!"
>>> def generate_tuples(string, n):
...     return [string[i:i+n] for i in range(len(string)-n+1)]
... 
>>> generate_tuples(a, 3)
['Hel', 'ell', 'llo', 'lo,', 'o, ', ', W', ' Wo', 'Wor', 'orl', 'rld', 'ld!']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for

```
>>> st="Hello, World!"
>>> [st[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0,len(st)-2)]
['Hel', 'ell', 'llo', 'lo,', 'o, ', ', W', ' Wo', 'Wor', 'orl', 'rld', 'ld!']
```

or if you want you can write it as a function:

```
>>> def generateTuples(st,n):
        return [st[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0,len(st)-n+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> text = "Hello, World!"
>>> map(''.join,zip(*(text[i:] for i in range(3))))
['Hel', 'ell', 'llo', 'lo,', 'o, ', ', W', ' Wo', 'Wor', 'orl', 'rld', 'ld!']
```

Comment: This is a bizarre but very very clever solution.  Took me a bit to figure out exactly what was going on here.  It strikes me as too confusing for use in regular code, but after working out the logic it strikes me as a quite elegant solution.  +1'd for teaching me something.

Comment: I think this is probably the most elegant solution IMO although it is definitely not good if you are looking for the most efficient code... :\

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> text = "Hello, World!"
>>>
>>> def subseqs(seq, length):
...     for i in xrange(len(seq) - length + 1):
...         yield seq[i:i+length]
...
>>> map(''.join, subseqs(text, 3))
['Hel', 'ell', 'llo', 'lo,', 'o, ', ', W', ' Wo', 'Wor', 'orl', 'rld', 'ld!']
```